# How to embed HTML table code into confluence

Tags: html, confluence

I have written code for HTML table. It works well and fine in browser but same code is not working in confluence page.(HTML macro). Is there any specific plugin/macro which needs to be enabled? please help me. Thanks in advance.

HTML Table is not displaying in confluence.